# How to write regex to extract a string delimited by two periods even if the first periods is not present

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to extract a string delimited by two periods even if the first period is not present.

```
Example 1:
Source string: fwe4d.tobe-extracted.s4red
Output string: tobe-extracted

Example 2:
Source string: tobe-extracted.s4red
Output string: tobe-extracted
```

I wrote the following regex but it only works if two periods are present.

```
$pattern = "/\.([^\.]+)\./";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group and an anchor:

```
^(?:[^\s.]+\.)?([^\s.]+)\.
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^\s.]+\.)?` Optionally match 1+ non whitespace chars without a dot, and then match `.`
- `([^\s.]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars or a dot
- `\.` Match the second dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zjLQ5N/1)